# objectdatasource insertparameter value

Tags: .net, parameters, objectdatasource

i have a page prueba.aspx with this code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Object ob = CPUSControl1.FindControl("ObjectDataSourcecpus");
            ObjectDataSource ods = (ob != null && ob.GetType() == typeof(ObjectDataSource)) ? (ObjectDataSource)ob : null;
            if (ods != null)
            {
                ods.SelectParameters.Clear();
                ods.SelectParameters.Add("usuario", DropDownListUsuarios.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());
                ods.InsertParameters.Add("usuario", DropDownListUsuarios.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            throw error;
        }


    }
```

CPUSControl1 is a usercontrol in this page and its found ok, the objectdatasource if found ok too. Even de selectedparameters works ok but the insertparameter i add does not work. I've tried to change the name, debugedit step by step and the insertparameters allways takes the defaultvalue(0)
The objectdatasource is this

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourcecpus" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getCPUs" TypeName="CPU" InsertMethod="saveCPUs">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="usuario" DefaultValue="0" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="usuario" DefaultValue="0" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Codigo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NroSerie" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TipoCPU" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Mother" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Modelo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Procesador" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Memoria" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Proveedor" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BocaRed" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IP" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UPS" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VtoGarantia" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FechaCompra" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NombreEquipo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="USB" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Obs" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Marcacion" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TipoCPU1" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fechaentrada" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fechasalida" Type="DateTime" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

i've been obligated to add the ods.SelectParameters.Clear(); but not a ods.InsertedParameters.Clear();
why?
i guess it's because i'm never adding the insertparameters but y cant guess why.
Thanks in advance. And excuse my bad english

Comment: Sounds like you want a [ControlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - no custom code required!

Comment: Hello Richard, thank you for your response. I've tried to use a ControlParameter but the dropdownlist is in the page that contain the usercontrol. So i can't point it from the objectdatasource in the usercontrol.

Comment: plus i think point from the user control to the main page is a quite dirty

Comment: i've add two labels in usercontrol and put this in pageload
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Label2.Text = ObjectDataSourcecpus.InsertParameters["usuario"].DefaultValue.ToString();
        Label3.Text = ObjectDataSourcecpus.SelectParameters["usuario"].DefaultValue.ToString();
}
the SelectParameters fill the label ok, the insertparameters does never fill it. So i've added an breakpoint after set de insertparameters and the "usuario" remains 0, like i'm not be able to change it.
There is a lot of examples i've found when people does this... i really don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ObjectDataSource ods = CPUSControl1.FindControl("ObjectDataSourcecpus") as ObjectDataSource;
   if (ods != null)
   {
      string value = DropDownListUsuarios.SelectedValue.Trim();
      ods.SelectParameters["usuario"].DefaultValue = value;
      ods.InsertParameters["usuario"].DefaultValue = value;
   }
}
```

Changes to your code:

- Don't catch an `Exception` if you're not going to do anything with it. (If you must re-throw an exception, use `throw;` instead of `throw error;` to preserve the stack-trace.)
- Use [the `as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx) for conditional casting of reference types - it's more efficient than calling `.GetType()` and comparing the result to a specific type.
- The `SelectedValue` property is already a `string` - there's no need to call `.ToString()` on it.
- Calling `.Trim()` creates a new string; it's best to cache the result in a local variable and reuse it.
- You have already added the parameter to the `SelectParameters` and `InsertParameters` collection via markup. You just need to retrieve the existing `Parameter` object and set its `DefaultValue` property.

---

**Edit:**
The `InsertParameters` collection doesn't store changes in `ViewState`, so you'll lose the value on post-back. The simplest solution is probably to use the `Inserting` event to set the parameter value:

*Main page (code-behind):*

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CPUSControl1.Usuario = DropDownListUsuarios.SelectedValue.Trim();
}
```

*User control:*

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourcecpus" runat="server" 
   SelectMethod="getCPUs" TypeName="CPU" InsertMethod="saveCPUs"
   OnSelecting="DataSourceCallingMethod"
   OnInserting="DataSourceCallingMethod"
   OnUpdating="DataSourceCallingMethod"
   OnDeleting="DataSourceCallingMethod"
>
...
```

*User control (code-behind):

```
public string Usuario
{
   get { return (string)ViewState["Usuario"]; }
   set { ViewState["Usuario"] = value; }
}

protected void DataSourceCallingMethod(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
   e.InputParameters["usuario"] = Usuario;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete anwer! i've copied and pasted this and thanks that now i get the error!
'CPU' does not contain a property with the name 'usuario'.
Now, please tell me can't i user selectparameters and insertparameters to pass a variable to the get or save method of CPU class?

Comment: @llocani: It sounds like you're trying to use `<%# Bind("usuario") %>` somewhere in your usercontrol. You shouldn't need to do that, since you've set the `DefaultValue` of the parameter.